# How to get Spyder IDE to use Python 3 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, spyder

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

says:

> E: Unable to locate package spyder3

How can I install Spyder 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? I need some Python 3 features.

Comment: Have you got the universe ppa?

Comment: I have now ;-) What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have got the Universe PPA, you will need to update the `apt-get` cache by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And once the `apt-get` cache is updated the following command should now work to install:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```